# How to show real time data streaming.?

Tags: node.js

**I would like to represent the real time data in the form of graph what is the appropriate technique to do it.??**
Let say i have some sensor node which continuously publish data i want to represent these data through graph.
Technology i'm using
NodeJS for Server Programming with MQTT or CoAP.
Is there any way to do it in Node.js n what tool is require to plot the graph?

Comment: You need to give way more information here, what is your output method? is it a GUI, a webpage or something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/504554/hardillb i don't know more about it, i just have to need to plot a graph of publishing data in a webpage. publish data is changed frequently in each second i want to show this change data in the form of graph.

Comment: You can use D3.js or http://lightning-viz.org